# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError but class exists

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Intelij Idea. On project i use http://www.simplejavamail.org . After build and test run on server i got error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at org.simplejavamail.util.ConfigLoader.<clinit>(ConfigLoader.java:55)
        at org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder.<init>(EmailBuilder.java:153)
        at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:186) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

After googleing i add slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar to libraries, but after build it cause that same error. It's strange because if i trying import it in any project file IDE suggest it. I also try add slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, slf4j-jdk14-1.7.25.jar but it's stil doesnt't help.

Sorry if i don't write important informations. It's my first java project.

Comment: Can you tell us How are you adding it to libraries?

Comment: right click on project structure -> F4 -> liblaries -> green + and select jar file

Comment: You should add it under Modules-> in the Dependancies tab. Click the + and then `Jars or directories`

Comment: Also make sure that llibrary is added to the deployed artifact.